# php copy image increases file size

Tags: php

I am using php to resize and crop images. However the cropped image file is greater than ( much greater in some cases) than the original file. I even tried without cropping (copying the original image) but the resulting size is more than the original image.

```
$ImageName = '/IMAGES/testImage.jpg';

//Download the Image File

$base_url = 'https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/none/path/sa6549607c78f5c11/image/ia62ed3191fcc424f/version/1457278719/athens-european-best-destinations.jpg';
$image_size = getimagesize($base_url);
$image_width =  $image_size[0];
$image_height =  $image_size[1];

$src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($base_url);

//Copy Image Object To File 
imagejpeg($src_image, $ImageName, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Technically, the quality rate of the conversion is not derivable from
>   the jpeg data, it just tells the converter which tradeoff to make
>   between size and quality.
>
> Some converters store it in the EXIF data of the JPEG header though,
>   so if that is still present you can use it with exif_read_data on it,
>   and see if the compression information is returned.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746221/php-resized-image-has-larger-file-size)

Answer (score 0):

try to reduce quality and set 80 for example. Quality will be still ok, it's even higher then default quality which should be 75 if you set nothing.

So, put like this:

```
imagejpeg($src_image, $ImageName, 80);
```

Comment: I think this's not OP mind. He want to ask what different 100% quality with original image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this [ImageCopyResampled](http://php.net/imagecopyresampled) in this case if you want to keep every pixel like original image. It's slower but better than imagejpeg.

And about quality of image using `imagejpeg` the quaility property refers to how much jpeg compression you want to apply to the saved or created output image.

0% quality means maximum compression and 100% quality means minimum compression.

The more compression you apply, the smaller the output filesize will be relative to the original uncompressed filesize.

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude the image quality parameter:

```
imagejpeg($src_image, $ImageName);
```

GD will automatically create a smaller image for you